# How to handle filenames with commas

Tags: symbols, external-files

Is there an easy way to call files that have commas in their names? I can usually manage it OK when there's a single input for a command, but LaTeX naturally gets confused when a command has multiple inputs, as these are usually separated by commas. To clarify:

Calling "file,name.txt" works:

```
\command{file,name.txt}
```

Calling "file,name.txt" with another input won't work:

```
\command{file,name.txt,variable}
```

Is there something like brackets that could clarify to LaTeX where the input starts and ends, e.g.:

```
\command{[file,name.txt],variable}
\command{"file,name.txt",variable}
```

I realise renaming the file would resolve this issue, but I'd like to know if an alternative exists.

Comment: Without knowing what `\command` is supposed to do, there's little to say.

Comment: Most likely you can use an extra set of braces `\command{{file,name.tex},variable}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use braces:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{listcntr}
\newcommand{\command}[1]{%
  \setcounter{listcntr}{0}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{listcntr}\par\thelistcntr: ##1}%
  \docsvlist{#1}}

\begin{document}

\command{[file,name.txt],variable}% 3 elements
\command{"file,name.txt",variable}% 3 elements
\command{{file,name.txt},variable}% 2 elements

\end{document}
```